# Connecting two or more MIDI connections to a single MIDI in/out ports

Tags: midi

I have a Yamaha organ with MIDI in/out ports. I have a Yamaha MDR-5 data recorder connected to the organs MIDI. Now, there is the MIDITZER virtual theater pipe organ I have on my computer that I can connect via a MIDI interface via USB to the organ's MIDI ports. I know I cannot use both at the same time, so what I need is a MIDI controller or whatever so I can connect the MIDTZER program from the computer and the MDR-5 to the input side in/out of said device, and the output side (in/out) of the device to the organ, and have the ability to switch between the two like A/B or 1,2. I have no thru MIDI port. I hope anyone can understand what I'm trying to accomplish. Thank you very much whoever can help me.

Comment: There are MIDI router devices (e.g., from [iConnectivity](http://www.iconnectivity.com/products/midi)). But might it be possible to do what you want with two USB/MIDI interfaces, and routing everything through the computer?

Answer (score 0):

With the prevalence of USB Midi which generally needs to run through a central computer (admittedly there are devices acting as a USB host for Midi routing purposes but they are typically more expensive than a second-hand laptop), I would expect the computer operating system to facilitate routing more easily than the traditional Midi-Through chaining.

The sound subsystem ALSA on Linux offers the `aconnect` program for configuring Midi connections.  These connections are then routed in the kernel without involving the delays inherent with a userspace application.

I should hope that other operating systems commonly used for music applications would offer similar facilities.  Processing music warrants predictable latencies, and switching to a 12Mbps connection (USB1.1) from a 31.25kps connection (current-loop Midi) should not cause the situation to deteriorate.  Famous last words and all that, I know.